# MYSQL insert is not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

Technically it accepts all the input but there no any error message that there is something wrong with my code. The insert is located at the bottom part of the code which is strangely not working because I tried my insert statement in the database and of course changing the variables with real values and it worked that way.

Tried this insert statement in my workbench and it worked:

```
INSERT INTO members (organization,login,password,name,title,profil,created,logout_time,timezone) VALUES ('1','Kristen','123','Kristen Crooks','Volunteer','2','2016-10-11 14:09','0','0')
```

Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    <center><b> Volunteer Management </b></center>

    <center>
    <a href="index.php">Add User </a>
    <a href="add_skill.php"> Add Skills </a>
    <a href="assign_user.php">Assign User</a>
    </center>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

        $config = parse_ini_file('/config.ini'); 


        $conn = new mysqli($config['servername'], $config['username'], $config['password'], $config['database']);

        if ($conn->connect_error) {
             die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

        $sql = "SELECT skillName FROM skills";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        $num=mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $conn->close();
    ?>
    <form method="get">

        Username: <br>
        <input type="text" name="username"> <br>
        Password: <br>
        <input type="text" name="password"> <br>
        Name: <br>
        <input type="text" name="name"> <br>
        Title: <br>
        <input type="text" name="title"> <br> <br>


        Permission:

        <select id="permission" name="permission">
            <option selected disabled>Choose here</option>
            <option value="0">Admin</option>
            <option value="1">Project Manager</option>
            <option value="2">Volunteer</option>
            <option value="6">Accounting Officer</option>
        </select> <br><br>



        Skills: <br>

        <?php

            $i=0;while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            $skillName=$row['skillName']; 

        ?>

        <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="<?php echo $skillName; ?>" ><?php echo $skillName; ?><br>

        <?php $i++;} ?>
        <br>

        <input type="submit" name="submit">

    </form>

    <?php
            if(isset($_GET['submit']))
            {
                $config = parse_ini_file('/config.ini'); 


                $conn = new mysqli($config['servername'], $config['username'], $config['password'], $config['database']);

                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                } 

                 $login = $_GET['username'];
                 $password = $_GET['password'];
                 $name = $_GET['name'];
                 $title = $_GET['title'];
                 $profil = $_GET['permission'];
                 $created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                 $sql = "INSERT INTO members (organization,login,password,name,title,profil,created,logout_time,timezone) 
                                        VALUES ('1','$login','$password','$name','$title','$profil','$created','0','0')";
                 $result = $conn->query($sql) or die('Error, insert query failed');

                 $conn->close();
            }
    ?>



</body>
```

Comment: There's no errors because you never bother checking for them. And since you `$conn->close()` your connection BEFORE you actually use your results, there's no way to fetch the results.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.Having said that, if you add a ' to any of the fields, the insert won't work

Comment: `"but there no any error message"` - This code doesn't actually *check* for errors coming from the database.  Ignoring errors isn't the same thing as not having any.  And given the SQL injection vulnerabilities here, you could be trying to execute *anything* in that SQL query, which could be failing in *any* way.

Comment: @MarcB But instantiated another connection when I want to submit the statement. I does not have any difference

Comment: Have you checked PHP error log?

Comment: @TarlanMammadzada Recently checked it and there is no error or whatsoever to give a clue on what problem should I address

Comment: As I wrote in answer, put an ECHO before Insert to check if script comes there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I already dissected the code and it appears that the `$created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` is causing the error. By the time I tried not to include it in the data in the insert statement, it worked! I guess I have to get another way to get the date from the system.

Also I've checked  that the reason why there is an error is because the date format is in VARCHAR and not in date and another problem is that it does not fit in the length that set. Although I want to ask why it is not detected by the server that there is an error like that

Answer (score -1):

1. Check PHP log and mysql log, write what is there.
2. Put an echo before the INSERT, check if your script comes to that place.

If echo is not working- then the problem is not in INSERT

Comment: This literally makes no difference whatsoever.

Comment: Changing how the string is built does NOT change the resulting string. `$x = "a" . "b"` v.s. `$x = "ab"` produce the EXACT SAME STRING. doesn't matter if you're interpolating variables or not, the exact same string is produced.

Comment: What about Mysql log? Also, have you put echo before Insert to check?

Comment: MySQL logs does not have any errror. Putting echo is still not working

Comment: If echo is not working, then the problem is not in INSERT! )

Comment: Put the echo just after if(isset($_GET['submit'])). Check if that condition is met.